# How to hide the cursor in windows when dragging and dropping (possibly in python, or another language)

Tags: python, windows, winapi, com

After hours of searching google, with little luck, I'm wondering if anybody knows how to either hide the cursor, or set a custom cursor (which could be made blank) in Windows when dragging and dropping.

I'm writing a program which draws its own mouse using openGL, and normally the mouse hides just fine, but when I drag files onto the program's window, the windows cursor shows the drag-and-drop square and will not hide. ShowCursor(False) and SetCursor(None) (in python) are inconsistent for hiding the cursor.

Ideally, if anybody knew how to do this in Python using pywin32, that would be ideal, as that's the language my project is using, but if I have to code this up in another language I will.

Alternately, if anybody knows when ShowCursor and SetCursor will guarantee to hide the cursor, whether this has to do with window focus or something related, that would also be helpful.

I've found this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop.aspx#Y1354
I cannot get the C++ code to compile, and I get exceptions when I use the C# and VB versions. I've copied cursors from C:\Windows\Cursors to the directory with the executable as 3dwarro.cur and 3dwno.cur. When I comment out the try clauses, when it tries to load the cursors it says they are corrupt.

I've also found this page: http://www.rockhoppertech.com/java-drag-and-drop-faq.html. It says to set the DragContext's cursor to null and then to your cursor in dragOver. The page is in Java, and I don't know how to do what it is saying.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is the custom cursor important?

Comment: The program is dealing with some experimental stuff in 3D, so the cursor polygon is warped in OpenGL. Also, I'm using the typical "full screen" application method of measuring mouse movement by repeatedly setting the  windows mouse to the center of the screen, so once the mouse hits the OpenGL window with a file being dragged, it's repeatedly centered, and flickers back and forth.

Comment: If the drag image is created by `ImageList_SetDragCursorImage`, then the cursor you are seeing isn't the cursor at all, but just a combined image.

Comment: Would it be drawn by that even if there is no image displayed? I'm seeing something like this on top of my window: http://blog.epicedits.com/wp-content/uploads/drag-n-drop-99.png That said, the ImageList_SetDragCursorImage appears to only combine an image with the mouse cursor image, can it replace the cursor image itself?

Comment: Which API are you using to give feedback on the drag? I assume you're not implementing `IDropSource::GiveFeedback` yourself as you would know not to return `DRAGDROP_S_USEDEFAULTCURSORS` therefore allowing you to set a custom cursor.

Comment: My drag and drop code is almost exactly taken from here: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2008-April/007409.html It uses the win32api for python and python COM wrappers. I just added the stuff I wanted it to do to DragEnter, Drop, etc.

Comment: Neil: just to clarify, what I'm writing is a drop source, not a drop target. The source will almost always be Windows Explorer (a folder, a desktop, etc.). Right now, those programs are setting DRAGDROP_S_USEDEFAULTCURSORS, so unless I'm going to hack open Windows Explorer and change the code, that' won't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Windows SDK:

> ShowCursor: This function sets an
>   internal display counter that
>   determines whether the cursor should
>   be displayed. The cursor is displayed
>   only if the display count is greater
>   than or equal to 0.

So you should try the equivalent of:

```
while ShowCursor(False) >= 0 do ;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work, the drag and drop cursor is still displayed when the function is returning values of -1 and -2. Might this be because my window does not have focus? (I have tried in past to bring the window to the foreground, with little luck).

Comment: I found this page, which says some versions of windows ignore SetCursor(Null). Perhaps the behaviour is the same for ShowCursor? http://en.allexperts.com/q/C-1040/hide-system-cursor.htm

Comment: Correction: the above code works some of the time, and I can't figure out when, because it is not dependent on my window being the foreground window.