# Disable cursor During Drag and Drop Operation

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have implemented this WPF drag and drop framework by Jan Karger (2011) https://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/

However, I cannot seem to change [the default cursor which appears during a Drag and Drop operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGaN2.png):

I understand that the cursor is affected somehow by the `DragDropEffects.Copy` method, however I cannot seem to override or change it at all.

If anyone could shed some light on this problem, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It would be greatly appreciated if you could show us some code on how you are handling the Drag & Drop, to better assist you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right there on the main documentation page: if you follow the exact same model with ViewModels implementing the interfaces, then you need to have an IDropTarget. The drop target controls what icon is displayed, of course - different targets might have different effects.

So in the handler for DragOver, you receive a DropInfo - simply set its Effects property to the value you'd like.

I used that library once and I remember it being really neat - a simple wrapper that brought MVVM to drag/drop. I distinctly remember having different drag icons (and even more complicated stuff like semi-transparent overlay of the stuff being dragged) so I'm sure it's possible. If you're sure you're doing everything right and it still doesn't work, then much more detail will be needed...

Comment: Hi @AlexPaven, sorry about that this is my code in the DefaultDropHandler class: 

`if (CanAcceptData(dropInfo))
            {
                dropInfo.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
                
                dropInfo.DropTargetAdorner = DropTargetAdorners.Insert;
            }`

I can change the DragDropEffects to different properties, however I cannot disable or hide the cursor. Do you know how I can go about this?

Comment: Ah you mean hiding as in not displaying it at all as opposed to setting the effects to None? That's much more involved as the underlying implementation is all handled by Windows after all... a good starting point might be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272428/how-to-hide-the-cursor-in-windows-when-dragging-and-dropping-possibly-in-python but I don't know much more than that.